# Using special characters like parenthesis (),asterisk *.. in where condition

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Whenever I try to fetch value from one table of my database. In my query, I put special character like `(),*,-..etc` for e.g,

```
Select * from table_name where col_name='Emlysium(infra)'
or Select * from table_name where col_name='demo & intest'
```

If I am using above queries, then this queries are not useful to get proper values and they are showing empty value because I have used Special characters.

```
**Demo Table**

id | col_name | col_name2

1  | Emlysium(infra) | abc

2  | demo & intest   | mno

3  | jerry.pat       | xyz
```

So can u suggest me a solution by which we can compare values using  special characters .
eg.     Select * from table_name where **col_name='Emlysium(infra)**

```
********My code

$site = 'Emlysium(infra)';

function get($site)
{
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->where(array('running.site'=>$site));                             
        $query = $this->db->get('running');
        return $query->num_rows();
}
```

Comment: Will you please add your database table content in question? @Aurea

Answer (score 3):

You just write your query Using Active record. It automatically handle all escape character

```
$val = "Emlysium(infra)";
$this->db->select('subcat_id');
$this->db->where('col_name', $val);
$query = $this->db->get('table_name');
```

Answer (score 3):

Just escape every special character:

```
Select * from table_name where col_name='Emlysium\(infra\)'
```

OR

To get the row of table test where text = '*()asdf'

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE text = '\*\\\(\)asdf'
```

If you are passing parameters in php:

```
$qry = "SELECT * FROM test WHERE text = '" . addcslashes('*().;', '*()') . "'";
```

> [addcslashes (php.net)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addcslashes.php): Returns a string with backslashes before characters that are listed in charlist parameter.

Comment: What if I am passing as parameter and putting in where condition??

Comment: just use addcslashes($sql, '*()');